# In what way is String Theory "two-dimensional"?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory

This is from the [Wikipedia article of QFT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory):

> Various attempts at a theory of quantum gravity led to the development of string theory, itself a type of two-dimensional QFT with conformal symmetry.

What does "two-dimensional" mean in this regard? Is this related to the holographic principle?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is string theory a two dimensional quantum (conformal) field theory on its worldsheet?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121839/)

Answer (score 3):

A string worldsheet is 2D. One space dimension (how far you are along the string), one time dimension.

Comment: So it doesn't refer to the dimensionality of the QF domain?

Comment: This is true, but doesn't explain how this leads to a two dimensional CFT.